# How to set parameters for included T4 templates?

Tags: c#, parameters, t4, reusability

If I have a reusable T4 template, how can I set parameters when recalling it?

Consider these two example files...

Hello.t4:

```
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Name" #>
Hello <#= this.Name #>!
```

HelloWorld.tt:

```
Testing text templates,
<#@ include file="Hello.t4" #>
```

How to pass the string "World" as the "Name" parameter of the Hello.t4 template?